# Use ternary alike method for calling methods

Tags: java, android, methods, operators, ternary-operator

As we all now, you can use ternary operators like this:

```
String testString = "test";
int myInt = testString.equals("test") ? 1 : 2;
```

However, how can I do so with methods?
Assume I have the following:

```
String testString = "test";
if (testString.equals("test") {
    doSomething();
} else {
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

**Is there something where you can combine this like the following manner:**

```
testString.equals("test") ? doSomething() : doSomethingElse();
```

When using it in Android studio, it results in saying "not a statement"

**Edit**
It can be done by initializing a local variable, but it is a bit unusual.

```
public void test() {
    String testString = "test";
    boolean test = testString.equals("test") ? doSomething() : doSomethingElse(); 
}

public boolean doSomething() {
    return true;
}

public boolean doSomethingElse() {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You can. And you have the good syntax.

Comment: No you can't! it refers to it as "not a statement"

Comment: Use the `if` statement. It is already exactly what you want. The ternary operator is not a drop-in replacement for any `if` statement.

Comment: And btw: the good OO method of doing this is: `ThisOrThat whoCares = myFactory.getDoerFor("test"); whoCares.doIt()`. You **hide** the if as much as possible, and you then turn to OO/polymorphism with different implementation of the same interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only write

`testString.equals("test") ? doSomething() : doSomethingElse();`

if `doSomething()` and `doSomethingElse()` both return something, and those somethings have either exactly the same type, or are *covariant* types. Setting both functions to return a `boolean` would be sufficient.

This is because the entire thing is an *expression*, and an *expression* has a value as well as a well-defined type.

If you are not wanting to do anything with the return value, then use an `if` statement.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that will maybe resolve this is by letting both methods return a boolean, and let it be initialized as a variable. Example:
```boolean test = testString.equals("test") ? doSomething() : doSomethingElse();```

Where 
```public boolean doSomething() {return true;}``` and ```public boolean doSomethingElse() {return false;}```